# Rxjava2 and Retrofit2 Multiple/Parallel/Simultaneous api(post) calls on different threads

Tags: android, multithreading, parallel-processing, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have this code below where I'm trying to achieve multiple consecutive api calls using Retrofit2 + RxJava2

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count++;
            request.setName("rober");
            request.setVarryingValue(count);

            mApiService.apiService()
                    .getAccessToken(<params>)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .flatMap(new Function<Auth, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<?> apply(Auth authentication) throws Exception {

                            Observable<Void> postObservable = mApiService.apiService().postCall(request, authentication.getAuth())
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                            postObservable.subscribe(new Observer<Void>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(Void value) {
                                    Log.e("Thread", " Thread : " + Thread.currentThread());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {}
                            });

                            return postObservable;
                        }
                    }).subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object value) {}

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {}
            });
        }
    });
```

my expectation is that for every click, dispatch a call to a new/different thread to execute a specific api POST call, but im having these post values from the inner api call

```
{"name ":"rober"," some_varrying_number ":"4"}
04-03 07:23:08.319 27225-27378/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> END POST (1679-byte 
body)
04-03 07:23:08.322 27225-27380/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> POST 
http://mydomain.test.post.server http/1.1

{"name ":"rober"," some_varrying_number ":"4"}
04-03 07:23:08.319 27225-27378/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> END POST (1679-byte 
body)
04-03 07:23:08.322 27225-27380/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> POST 
http://mydomain.test.post.server http/1.1


{"name ":"rober"," some_varrying_number ":"4"}
04-03 07:23:08.319 27225-27378/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> END POST (1679-byte 
body)
04-03 07:23:08.322 27225-27380/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> POST 
http://mydomain.test.post.server http/1.1


{"name ":"rober"," some_varrying_number ":"4"}
04-03 07:23:08.319 27225-27378/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> END POST (1679-byte 
body)
04-03 07:23:08.322 27225-27380/edu.rx.test D/OkHttp: --> POST 
http://mydomain.test.post.server http/1.1
```

it seems like it only execute the last call, I've learned that theres no exactly "Parallel" call in Rx, because if it does, it will violate all the reactive principles, but theres alot of workaround for that they say, and now I'm trying to achieve that "Parallel" call with the codes i posted, but no luck :(, I need some help here,

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: The process would be like this
1. get auth token first
2. after a successfull auth token proceed to api POST calls

number 2 is dependent to number 1

1 & 2 will always execute on click events.

**Edit**: Ill post an image to illustrate it clearly

- I have 2 sources(this can be 3 or more)
- These sources come from click events
- Each source will process different network calls
- Im trying to execute it in different thread (to make it asynchronous)
- each will post different values on server
  [image]
- but it seems like it only process the last event(clicked)
- using the image above, im expecting POST A and POST B will happen in parallel/differently
- but it only executes POST B (2 POST B actually)
- im expecting that it will execute POST A & POST B differently

Comment: does 'request' is a field in a class that shared across each onClick? what is the thread issue problem, if any?
You have 4 calls in your log, didn't you? with the same parameters in the call, that is your problem?

Comment: im not really sure if thats a thread issue problem, I'm expecting that the count will increment and the "some_varrying_number" will have a value from the count (some_varrying_number  will increment as well), 

some_varrying_number : 1
some_varrying_number : 2
some_varrying_number : 3
some_varrying_number : 4

, but it seems like "some_varrying_number : 4" is the only value thats being executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you send the very first POST request, the `request`'s varying value is already 4. That's because after you click 4 times, then the first POST request will take the `request` at that time (with 4), not the `request` at the time its varying value is set.

The solution is making the `request` object be local inside the `onClick()` method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    RequestClass request = new RequestClass();
    request.setName("rober");
    request.setVarryingValue(count);

    //Your code
}
```

Or assign the `count` value to a temporary variable, and set it to your `request` right before sending the POST request, but watch out for thread-safety

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Saving the value
    int temp = count++;
    request.setName("rober");

    mApiService.apiService()
            .getAccessToken(<params>)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .flatMap(new Function<Auth, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(Auth authentication) throws Exception {
                    //Set it to the request
                    //BE CAREFUL  because the `request` object is now being accessed from multiple threads
                    request.setVarryingValue(temp);

                    Observable<Void> postObservable = 
                        mApiService
                            .apiService()
                            .postCall(request, authentication.getAuth())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe();

                    return postObservable;
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: I want to upvote both yosriz and your answer as an accepted one, i manage to make what i want(it solved it) with making the field as local, instead of as a field shared among the class, but please, can you explain why? I know it has something to do with threading, or can you please give me a link related to my problem and solution you gave? there atleast I can understand the difference between a field and a local when it comes to rx

Comment: Edit: I made the Request local instead of field not the count variable as you are right, race conditions may arise here and i dont want to introduce synchronization

Comment: If you use `request` as a field, all the `onClick` call will access to the same instance of `RequestClass`. In your situation, when one of the four GET requests returns AFTER 4 `onClick` executions, you send the first POST request with the shared instance of `RequestClass`, its varying value is 4 after the fourth `onClick`. In the local case, all the four executions of `onClick` will user four different instances of `RequestCall`, so no `onClick` will be able to edit the value of others.

Comment: It's quite not related to threading, since all the four `onClick` are executed on main thread, but it's the diferrent between a local variable and a field. Try some OOP tutorials about that topic will help you clear things out.

Comment: "Try some OOP tutorials about that topic will help you clear things out" - yeah I think i need some refresh on basics, 

Edit: I went to a room with a white board, and draw everything you said, yeah you are right, its not concurrency, I just missed a fundamental characteristics of java, on the 4th request of GET, the value already incremented for the Request object, now when the GET responded, it will use the latest value of Request object which is 4, thanks so much, really thanks

Comment: I should have stepped back a bit, i forgot the basics thinking too much of Reactive/Concurrency things

Comment: Im glad you did. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear to me why are all the post requests are done at the same time, a full log with `onClick()` timing and the `getAccessToken()` requests, and `onNext()` emissions might help.

Your code seems to doing it right, you will open a new thread for each request.
But, anyhow, as you have 4 prints on your log, but all are of the same count, the problem is probably because the `request` param is a field and thus shared and accessed **after** `getAccessToken()` emit an item, thus you basically do 4 requests but with the same data.
You should assign for each new created `flatMap()` a dedicated count variable.

Besides that, it's wrong to subscribe to the `postObservable` inside the `flatMap()` operator, you should just return it and the stream will subscribe to it and merge it back as `onNext()` emissions.
With your code, you're executing each post request **twice**, one explicitly  by you and the other by the `flatMap()` operator (that might also explains multiple logs of the same request, but again it's hard to tell without seeing all the data in log) .

Comment: thanks to both of you for clarifying the issue that I should make the value local to the method instead of a field, would you mind to elaborate this one "it's wrong to subscribe to the postObservable inside the flatMap() operator, you should just return it and the stream will subscribe to it and merge it back as onNext() emissions.", how can I chain the call without using/subscribing another observer inside the flatmap?

Comment: I suggest you to read a bit more about flatMap, that's exactly what flatMap() does, it will create an Observable from each onNext value (according to your mapping function), then it will subscribes to it and merge the emission from this new Observable to source stream.

Answer (score 0):

Based on both of your suggested answers, I came up with the following code,

- Request became a local variable instead of a field
- Removal of subscription inside flat map
- Chained it on onNext of the outer observable

  ```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  count++;
  Request request = new Request();
  request.setName("rober");
  request.setVarryingValue(count);

  mApiService.apiService()
          .getAccessToken(<params>)             
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .flatMap(new Function<Auth, ObservableSource<Void>>() {
              @Override
              public ObservableSource<Void> apply(Auth authentication) throws Exception {
                  return mApiService.apiService().postCall(request, authentication.getAuth());
              }
          })  
          .subscribe(new Observer<ObservableSource<Void>>() {

              @Override
              public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

              @Override
              public void onNext(ObservableSource<Void> sourceFromFlatMap) {

                  sourceFromFlatMap.subscribe(new Observer<Void>() {

                      @Override
                      public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

                      @Override
                      public void onNext(Void value) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                      @Override
                      public void onComplete() {}
                  });
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable e) {}

              @Override
              public void onComplete() {}
          });
   });
  ```

though I'm still not sure if I'm using Rx in the proper way